# What is a good StringTemplate plugin for Eclipse, so i can do cod gen?

Tags: eclipse, modeling, codegen

I'm working on a eclipse-based model-based tool. I am not using UML/SysML but i created my own DSML (= component architecture, whereby components have a behavior, modeled using state automatons). 
What I want to do now is to be able generate code and some config files from this model. So the question is: are there any good plugins out there, which would support that? (Tutorials wouldnt hurt either)
I did something similar in tool MPS (by jetbrains). It offers a string template language, that can be used for code gen. It would be cool to find something similar to it.

There is a plugin called StringTemplateDT in the eclipse market place. Does anyone have any experience with that?

best and thanks

Jenny

Answer (score 0):

Give JET (Java Emitter Template) a try, it was relatively easy to pick up. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJET/article.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I stumbled across the eclipse m2t website (https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/). There are 3 different frameworks listed there: JET, Acceleo and XPand. Which of those 3 are the best if i want to do some simple code gen (C-files and config flies) based on my models?